# Passenger Hanging after Restart - Shared Hosting Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

Last night I made a revision to [app-root]/config/initializers/refinery/core.rb and the touched [app-name]/tmp/restart.txt. Then I tried to reload the app to find it totally hanging. The other two RoR apps I'm running on the same server were also hanging. Per curl -v there was no response at all from the server.

Everything was working fine before I touched the restart.txt file. The following morning, seven or eight hours later, the sites are working again and my minor edit (the site name) is showing up.

Rails 3.2.16 on a hostmonster linux server.

The instance of Passenger is not running under my user so I wonder if my hang horned any other user's RoR sites?

I can't restart apache (of course) since this is a shared server. Any suggestions for how to deal with this if it happens again? I have no budget for Heroku or a VPS.

UPDATE: Did the same steps again this morning, revised the core.rb and asked for a restart by touching restart.txt and it restarted in less than a minute. The question remains valid I think - what can a person do to address a hanging Passenger or prevent it from happening?

Comment: Which version of Phusion Passenger?

Comment: You could try `digitalocean.com` that provides a very affordable VPS. I have used it and its very developer friendly.

Comment: @Hongi, I don't know. Passenger is running on the server and I'm just a user on the server. When do a "gem contents passenger" I get "Unable to find gem 'passenger' in default gem paths"

Comment: @Bala thanks for the suggestion, but even $5 a month is more than I can afford right now. The site is for a non-profit with no budget and I'm in very low budget mode myself at the moment.

Comment: I am also having this problem. The site will work fine...I will make a few changes....ill do `touch tmp/restart.txt` and BAM itll hang